# My discord Bot is Unable to read DM messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I know that "**the CHANNEL partial must be enabled**" and it is. But my bot still can't recognize DM messages.

Here is my code:

```js
const client = new Client({intents:[...],partials:[Partials.Channel,...]});

client.on("messageCreate", (message) =>{
if (message.channel.type === 'DM') console.log('Dm recieved');
})
```

All the other parts of the bot work except this part.

Comment: can you show a full list of intents that you have?

Comment: Guilds, GuildMessages, GuildMembers, GuildPresences, MessageContent,DirectMessages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the [guide on how to handle events](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/event-handling.html#event-handling). My personal recommendation is to use an [individual file type event handler](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/event-handling.html#individual-event-files)

Example:

```
const { Events } = require('discord.js');

client.once(Events.messageCreate, message => {
    console.log(`Message event triggered! Message: {message.content}`);
});
```

My recommendation (individual file type event handler):

```
for (const file of eventFiles) {
  const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
  console.log(`| ✅ ${file} loaded!`);

  if (event.once) {
    client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, commands));
  } else {
    client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, commands));
  }
}
```

```
module.exports = {
  name: "messageCreate",
  once: false,
  async execute(message) {
    // Your code to handle messages
  }
}
```

You can also try logging in the event to check if it's being triggered correctly.

If the above answers do not work, you can try this:

```
if (message.channel.isDMBased())
```